# How can I make menuitems in a viewcell.contextactions show up on the correct page in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, maui

The code below works perfectly fine except for the toolbaritem (along with everything in <ViewCell.ContextActions>) showing up in a previous page when running the program. I've tried using menuitems instead, but those also seem to show up on another page.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <toolkit:SelectedItemEventArgsConverter x:Key="SelectedItemEventArgsConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Back" x:Name="ReturnToHomePageButton" Clicked="ReturnToHomePageButton_Clicked"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<VerticalStackLayout>
    <ListView
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Review}"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    RefreshControlColor="Red"
    SelectionMode="None"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Review">
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <ToolbarItem
                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReviewPage}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            IsDestructive="True"
                            Text="Delete" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label
                                        FontSize="Large"
                                        Text="{Binding Username}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <controls:SimpleRatingControl 
                                        Amount="5"
                                        CurrentValue="{Binding Stars}"
                                        AccentColor="Yellow"
                                        StarSize="36" 
                                        VerticalOptions="End" />
                                    <Label
                                        FontSize="Small"
                                        Text="{Binding Text}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

`

The project has two views/pages, the mainpage and the infopage. The infopage displays several reviews in the listview (as shown in the code above), but when long clicking these reviews to show the toolbaritem under contextactions, the toolbaritem shows up in the mainpage instead of the infopage.

Infopage with example review
[image: Infopage with example review]

Mainpage after long clicking a review
[image: Mainpage after long clicking a review]

Infopage after long clicking a review (nothing changes)
[image: Infopage after long clicking a review (nothing changes)]

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking.  Are you saying that the context menu is mysteriously showing up on a different page that does not even contain the same ListView?  Can you aatach a screenshot or video that demonstrates this?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening. The mainpage has a button to go to the infopage, but other than that it has nothing else.

Comment: that's really bizarre.  Can you post a [mcve] or link to your solution repo?

Comment: Solution repo: https://github.com/K-Ketchup/iPantherToilets

Comment: You should have missed uploading some files, at least I didn't see `.sln` files. Then I created a demo and added your code to my demo, but the app crashed when I added an item into the database.  Could you please upload the missing file?

Comment: Sorry about that, you should see the .sln file now. It's also strange that the app crashed when adding an item to the database though, that definitely shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Are you sure you have uploaded all the files correctly? I can't load your app correctly.

Comment: Definitely should be all of them. If there's issues with loading the app itself, I think there might be some bigger issues behind the program. I'll try to identify this issue first before getting back to you all, thank you!

Comment: Waiting for your good news.  :)